# Error: undefined reference to NetCDF functions

Tags: linux, fortran, linker-errors, gfortran, netcdf

#### Background

I'm working on compiling [MCIP](https://github.com/CMASCenter/MCIP/tree/4.3) which mean Meteorology Chemistry Interface Processor in centos 5.9 system.

I use gcc -version 4.9 to implement the process.

#### Setting

Here is some configuration setting in ~/.bashrc:

```
export DIR=/disk2/hyf/lib ## All lib ar installed under this path
# NetCDF setting
export PATH="$DIR/netcdf/bin:$PATH"
export NETCDF="$DIR/netcdf"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$NETCDF/lib     
# IOAPI 
export BIN=Linux2_x86_64gfort
export BASEDIR=/disk2/hyf/backup/software/ioapi
export PATH=$DIR/ioapi-3.1/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DIR/ioapi-3.1/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
# Set M3LIB for the model
export M3LIB=/disk2/hyf/cmaq/CMAQv5.1/lib
```

I also do soft link for the CMAQ model as these:
    ln -s $NETCDF $(M3LIB)/x86_64/gcc/netcdf
    ln -s $IOAPI $(M3LIB)/x86_64/gcc/ioapi

#### Makefile

Here is some subroutine in the **Makefile**:

```
 # Requirements: set M3LIB before running this script

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .o .f90 .F90

MODEL = mcip.exe

#...gfortran
FC      = gfortran
NETCDF = $(M3LIB)/netcdf
IOAPI_ROOT = $(M3LIB)/ioapi
FFLAGS  = -O3 -gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf -I$(NETCDF)/include -   I$(IOAPI_ROOT)/include \
      -ffpe-trap='invalid','zero','overflow','underflow'
##FFLAGS        = -g -O0  \
      -ffpe-trap='invalid','zero','overflow','underflow'  \
      -I$(NETCDF)/include -I$(IOAPI_ROOT)/include
LIBS    = -L$(IOAPI_ROOT)/lib -lioapi  \
      -L$(NETCDF)/lib -lnetcdf -lgomp

DEFS   =

MODULES =\
 const_mod.o \
 const_pbl_mod.o \
 coord_mod.o \
 date_time_mod.o \
 date_pack_mod.o \
 files_mod.o \
 groutcom_mod.o \
 luvars_mod.o \
 mcipparm_mod.o \
 mcoutcom_mod.o \
 mdoutcom_mod.o \
 metinfo_mod.o \
 metvars_mod.o \
 vgrd_mod.o \
 wrf_netcdf_mod.o \
 xvars_mod.o \
 sat2mcip_mod.o

OBJS =\
 mcip.o \
 alloc_ctm.o \
 alloc_met.o \
 alloc_x.o \
 bcldprc_ak.o \
 blddesc.o \
 chkwpshdr.o \
 chkwrfhdr.o \
 close_files.o \
 collapx.o \
 comheader.o \
 cori.o \
 dealloc_ctm.o \
 dealloc_met.o \
 dealloc_x.o \
 detangle_soil_px.o \
 e_aerk.o \
 dynflds.o \
 getgist.o \
 getluse.o \
 getmet.o \
 getpblht.o \
 getsdt.o \
 getversion.o \
 graceful_stop.o \
 gridout.o \
 init_io.o \
 init_met.o \
 init_x.o \
 julian.o \
 layht.o \
 ll2xy_lam.o \


 .......
```

#### ERROR

The output after I **make** shows like:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/disk2/hyf/cmaq/CMAQv5.1/scripts/mcip/src'
gfortran -g -O0 -gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf \ 
         -I/disk2/hyf/cmaq/CMAQv5.1/lib/x86_64/gcc/netcdf/include \      
         -I/disk2/hyf/cmaq/CMAQv5.1/lib/x86_64/gcc/ioapi/include  -c const_mod.f90
......

chkwpshdr.o: In function `chkwpshdr_':
/disk2/hyf/cmaq/CMAQv5.1/scripts/mcip/src/chkwpshdr.f90:109: \    
 undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_get_att_one_fourbyteint'

 (a lot of these code showing the same mistake 'undefined reference')  

 /disk2/hyf/cmaq/CMAQv5.1/lib/x86_64/gcc/ioapi/lib/libioapi.a(open3.o): In    
 function `open3_':
 open3.F:(.text+0x1531): undefined reference to `ncclos_'
 .........
```

I think the compiler may have some conflicts with the .F and .f90 files in some case. But I don't know why. The gcc andhas already successfully installed with $PATH defined.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ instead of Fortran?

Comment: Sorry, the website system just recommended 'c++' in the first place.

Comment: This is the netcdf which is linked incorrectly. Which version of NetCDF do you have? Where is it installed?

Comment: I use netcdf-version 4.13(The last version that the netcdf-c and fortran toghther). I installed it in another place and `ln -s $netcdf_PATH $(M3LIB)/x86_64/gcc/netcdf `

Comment: The netcdf should be installed correctly. Because other models have complied well.

Comment: It is `$NETCDF_PATH`, not `$netcdf_PATH`. And your Makefile uses just `$NETCDF`. Describe exactly what you have done in steps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll re-write it.

Comment: There are big parts of the Makefile missing. And of the error message too. How is `$LIBS` used in the Makefile? The error message **must** be shown *at least* with the last command executed before the error. You cannot just put `...` before the first error. You really must show that command.

Comment: Not sure about you, but when I compile Fortran Code with NetCDF, I need to add both `-lnetcdf` and `-lnetcdff` to the compile step.

Comment: @HanZhengzu have you got it to work?

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem, and I've got to solve it by adding -lnetcdff and -lnetcdf (in this order) to the LIBS option in the MCIP makefile. Make sure the NETCDF variable is pointing to the correct path where netcdf is installed in your system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check it later.